# how do use the ~ symbol with cloning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I built a 15 by 12 by 11 "plane". I am trying to use the command block /clone technique but I don't know what to put in each one.

In the pilot area of the plane I have 2 command blocks for each direction. I know one command block clones the plane in which ever direction I choose and the other command block teleports the person with the plane. I do not have the code for either of those blocks.

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands

Comment: So did you take those command blocks from somewhere else and want to understand how they work, or they don't actually teleport yet and you want them to?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the clone command syntax:

```
/clone [x1] [y1] [z1] [x2] [y2] [z2] [xdest] [ydest] [zdest] normal move
```

`[x1] [y1] [z1]` are the coordinates for the first corner of your plane. The clone command works in a rectangular area, so the first corner should be opposite to to second corner.

`[x2] [y2] [z2]` are just the second corners.

`[xdest] [ydest] [zdest]` are where the game will clone the area to. (Well, it will move it because in the command we are telling it to) This always clones based on the selected area's lowest X,Y, and Z. So make sure you do that right.

~'s can replace any coordinate, and they simply stand for the executor's (command block's) position. So ~-1 would be 1 block behind the command block.

I hope this helps!